# How to refresh my UIVIewController using SetNeedsDisplay

Tags: uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, xamarin

I have a simple UIViewController (in monotouch), with a button on the UI. Now, my use case is simple - I want to reload the UIViewController whenever the button is clicked. On some threads i read that i just need to call SetNeedsDisplay for the UIView, but that doesn't seem to work for me. Here is my code snippet -

```
public partial class AbcScreen : UIViewController
{
....
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        // Declare and Add a button
        Add(myBtn);
        myBtn.TouchUpInside += (sender, ea) =>
                {  
                    Console.WriteLine("Touched the button");
                    View.SetNeedsDisplay();
                };
    }
}
```

I read some other threads, but nothing seems to help. Please help! Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

Try with

```
this.ReloadInputViews();
```